# Aligning y-axis scales for side-by-side plots when one has legend and title in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, alignment

I want to create a plot that consists of two panels.  One panel is a raster plot showing the distribution of a variable z in x-y space.  The second panel is a simple line plot showing how another variable depends on y.  The y values for both the raster plot and the line plot are identical.  Here is an example code using grid.arrange to position the plots that shows the general idea:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

title <- "Example"

df2 <- data.frame(eruptions = faithfuld$eruptions, foo=faithfuld$eruptions*2)

pb <- ggplot(data=faithfuld, aes(x=waiting, y=eruptions, fill=density))
p1 <- pb + geom_raster() +
        theme(legend.position = "top") +
        guides(fill=guide_colorbar(title.position="top")) +
        ggtitle(title)

p2 <- ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=foo, y=eruptions)) + geom_line()

pout <- grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
print(pout)
```

The problem is that I'd like the y-axis on the right panel to match the y-axis of the left panel.  That is, the right panel should be reduced in size so that the y-axes of both panels are aligned.  I've searched through the archives for solutions but haven't found any questions that are similar to this problem.[image]

Comment: Have you tried the patchwork package?

Comment: No - I'll have a look.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about patchwork; it looks like a nice way to assemble a variety of plots, but I've looked at the manual and am not seeing anything that would allow me to determine the vertical extent of the y-axis on one plot and transfer that to the other.

Comment: Have you tried `p1 | p2` with patchwork?

Comment: No, I missed that, but that is the solution!  Many thanks!!!  I'll add an answer and give you credit for it.  I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

teunbrand posted a comment with a very simple solution to my problem.  Using the patchwork package, I changed the code as shown below.  This does exactly what I wanted to do.  Many thanks to teunbrand.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)
require(patchwork)

title <- "Example"

df2 <- data.frame(eruptions = faithfuld$eruptions, foo=faithfuld$eruptions*2)

pb <- ggplot(data=faithfuld, aes(x=waiting, y=eruptions, fill=density))
p1 <- pb + geom_raster() +
        theme(legend.position = "top") +
        guides(fill=guide_colorbar(title.position="top")) +
        ggtitle(title)

p2 <- ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=foo, y=eruptions)) + geom_line()

pout <- p1 | p2
print(pout)
```

[image]